# Why AtomicReference CAS return false with value 128?

Tags: java, concurrency, lock-free

I was using AtomicReference to implement AtomicInteger. However while in testing I notice even in single threaded environment the CAS operation got stuck once its value hit 128.. Am I doing something wrong or there is a caveat in AtomicReference (may be related to CPU)? Here is my code:

```
public class MyAtomInt {
  private final AtomicReference<Integer> ref;

  public MyAtomInt(int init) {
    ref = new AtomicReference<Integer>(init);
  }

  public MyAtomInt() {
    this(0);
  }

  public void inc() {
    while (true) {
      int oldVal = ref.get();
      int nextVal = oldVal + 1;
      boolean success = ref.compareAndSet(oldVal, nextVal); // false once oldVal = 128
      if (success) {
        return;
      }
    }
  }

  public int get() {
    return ref.get();
  }

  static class Task implements Runnable {

    private final MyAtomInt myAtomInt;
    private final int incCount;

    public Task(MyAtomInt myAtomInt, int cnt) {
      this.myAtomInt = myAtomInt;
      this.incCount = cnt;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      for (int i = 0; i < incCount; ++i) {
        myAtomInt.inc();
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    MyAtomInt myAtomInt = new MyAtomInt();
    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    exec.submit(new Task(new MyAtomInt(), 150)).get();
    System.out.println(myAtomInt.get());
    exec.shutdown();
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to implement your own `AtomicInteger` when the JDK provides it? Are you on a platform where it isn't supported, or is this an exercise?

Comment: This is just a practice to get familiar with the java.util.concurrent.atomic package, and yes we definitely don't need to re-invent the wheels :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason for this is that when you box an `int` into an `Integer`, you may or may not create a new `Integer` instance.  If you do, then the new instance may not have reference equality with other `Integer` instances, even if they share the same value.  `AtomicReference.compareAndSet()` uses *reference equality* (identity) for comparisons.

The key is in how the compiler handles automatic boxing of `int` values: it emits calls to `Integer.valueOf()`.  As an optimization, `Integer.valueOf()` has a cache of boxed integers, and by default that cache includes values up to 128.  If you box an integer `n` twice, you will get the same `Integer` reference back each time if the value was small enough to be in the cache; otherwise, you will get two separate instances.

Currently, you unbox the old value, compute the new value, and when you call `compareAndSet()` you box the old value *again*.  Once you hit 128, you stop getting cached values, so the second boxed copy is no longer the same one that's in the `AtomicReference`.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem! I was not aware that `AtomicReference.compareAndSet()` is based on reference comparison. After I replace the `int oldVal = ref.get();` with `Integer oldVal = ref.get();` to avoid auto-boxing, the code works fine.

Comment: Great!  Keep this in mind when if you have to implement `AtomicInteger.compareAndSet()` using an `AtomicReference` :).

Comment: And +1 for your explanation of `Integer.valueOf()` cache mechanism.